# TFDQuery causes the Failure of App to run on iOS Simulator (Delphi 10.3 Upd 3 Firemonkey)

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

I have issue with TFDQuery running on iOS platform having 2 TFDConnections with same SQLite drivers. The App is installed and tries to open but it closes right away without any error message. The error comes when the TFDQuery is set to active = true on either design time or runtime.

The reason why I am having 2 TFDConnections is one I need for RestAPI LocalSQL and the other is for my embedded database (SQLite3).

This issue I am not getting on Windows target platform. I am haven't tried yet with Android.

Here's my MRE for this case. Please note that I have not included the RestAPI LocalSQL in this example because the error is confined on the TFDConnections and TFDQuery only.

**FMX Procedure:**

```
unit main_u;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.Client, System.IOUtils,
  FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt,
  FireDAC.Comp.UI, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    con2: TFDConnection;
    qry1: TFDQuery;
    cur1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    dvr1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    con1: TFDConnection;
    procedure con2BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm9.con2BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
    con2.Params.Values['Database'] := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'smartcart.s3db');
  {$ELSE}
    con2.Params.Values['Database'] := 'D:\My Project Files\5. my_projects_aws-rest\project_x_v0\application\client\database\smartcart.s3db';
  {$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

FMX File:

```
object Form9: TForm9
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form9'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 289
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object con2: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      
        'Database=D:\My Project Files\5. my_projects_aws-rest\project_x_v' +
        '0\application\client\database\smartcart.sdb3'
      'LockingMode=Normal'
      'DriverID=SQLite')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    BeforeConnect = con2BeforeConnect
    Left = 128
    Top = 168
  end
  object qry1: TFDQuery
    Active = True
    Connection = con2
    SQL.Strings = (
      'SELECT * FROM lists')
    Left = 128
    Top = 232
  end
  object cur1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor
    Provider = 'FMX'
    Left = 80
    Top = 32
  end
  object dvr1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink
    Left = 24
    Top = 32
  end
  object con1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      'DriverID=SQLite')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 128
    Top = 112
  end
end
```

I've done some research and could not find any relevant solution to my case. I can say that the TFDQuery has some bugs or issues with regards to 2 TFDConnections with same drivers running at the same time on iOS platform.

Otherwise, I might have missed something here.

Comment: What is the failure? Which error or exception do you see, on which code line?

Comment: @fpiette Sorry, it wasn't so clear. The error is that the app was installed on iOS but it simply closes right away upon attempting to open without any error message. And I think the error comes when I set the TFDQuery to Active = True either at design time or runtime.

Comment: Instead of responding with comment, you should edit your question with the information you put in the comment.

Comment: Have you tried to run you application under the debugger?

Comment: I just got the error `Exception ESQLiteNativeException in module MultipleFDConnections.exe at 0000000000AB9840. [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: no such table: lists` but I checked the table `lists` and it is there.

Comment: Please ignore the error message, now it is solved. See my update. I am still getting the same issue on iOS platform and I couldn't use the debugger because it is running without any issue on Windows. I can't run the debugger on iOS.

Comment: Why can't you run the debugger under iOS? This would help a lot IMO.

Comment: @fpiette I am using Mac and run Delphi using Parallels for Windows. I am not sure if I can run the debugger on iOS Simulator. Normally, I could do that on Windows only. Otherwise, can you tell me how to run debugger under iOS?

Comment: First have a look at the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Debugging_Multi-Device_Applications#Debugging_iOS_Apps  Then do a little research by yourself and only then if needed, open a new question about debugging an iOS application.

Comment: @fpiette I am actually using iOS Simulator that's is the reason why I found out that there is an error. But there is no way that I could step over every procedure like in RAD in windows.